# how to process an array as get str to url?

Tags: php, javascript

how to process an array as get str to url?
I want to send an array to my PHP page as get prometers , don't care about how long the get str , it is only use in my site admin side. what should I process the array to a sting ,when in PHP site I can re process it back to array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function arr_to_get_str(arr){
        // how should I make a get string from an array? 
        // what format should this str shows
        return str;
    }

    var arr=[
        [
            key :'products_id',
            operator: '>',
            value : '20'
        ],
        [
            key :'products_name',
            operator: 'like',
            value : '%hello world%'
        ]
    ];
    var base_uri='http://localhost/test.php';
    var url= base_uri + '?'+ arr_to_get_str(str);
    location.href = url;

</script>
```

Comment: `[ key : 'value', ... ]` is not a valid Javascript array...!?!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should look like for the input array you showed (and fix the input since as deceze said it's not valid JS).

Comment: Neither It's a valid Javascript array nor JSON object. Correct it so that solution can be given accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complex data structure, the best encoding would be JSON. JSON is pretty inefficient in a URL though, as a lot of characters need to be inefficiently URL escaped. This may be a good use case for [Rison](http://mjtemplate.org/examples/rison.html). You can find a Javascript implementation on the site and a PHP implementation [here](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Rison).

Comment: Yeah, it's not widely known or used. As such, use at your own risk, since the libraries may not be as well tested as common JSON libraries. `</disclaimer>` :)

Comment: but I can not find how to encode my arr to rison string ,the page did not tells  how to use

Comment: @mingfish_004 http://mjtemplate.org/dist/mjt-0.9.2/rison.js, `var str = rison.encode(arr)`

Comment: php rison function do not support php5.2 , my website is used under php5.2, is there other rison php scripts works?

Comment: @mingfish_004 I don't know of another one. Shouldn't be too hard to backport that script to 5.2 though, I think mostly the namespacing is 5.3 specific. Why don't you fork it and edit it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather use `encodeURIComponent`:

```
var url= base_uri + '?q='encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

then php is:

```
$arrParameters = isset($_GET['q']) ? json_decode(url_decode(($_GET['q'])) : array();
```

This will get you the parameters or return an empty array if there are none. Not the best practice, but if it an "hackish" admin system, go for it

Comment: encodeURIComponent(URIstring) the prometer should be a string?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a JSON string of your array, & encode it into Base64 with [window.btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.btoa)

   > ```
   > var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
   > var encString  = window.btoa(jsonString); 
   > // supports all except- ie- below version 10
   > ```
2. Send it in request parameter

   > `var url= base_uri + '?request='+ arr_to_get_str(arr);`
3. In **.php** file, get the string & decode it to Array or Object

   > ```
   > $requestJsonStr = base64_decode($_GET['request']);
   >
   > //EITHER make an Array from the JSON-String
   > $requestArray = json_decode($requestJsonStr, TRUE);
   >
   > //OR make an Object from the JSON-String
   > $requestArray = json_decode($requestJsonStr, FALSE);
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function arr_to_get_str(arr){


  var str='';
    var strarr= new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        strarr.push(arr[i]['key']+' '+arr[i]['operator']+' '+arr[i]['value']);
    }
    str=strarr.join(' AND ');
    return str;
}

var arr=[
    {
        key :'products_id',
        operator: '>',
        value : '20'
    },
    {
        key :'products_name',
        operator: 'like',
        value : '%hello world%'
    }
];
var base_uri='http://localhost/test.php';
var url= base_uri + '?q='+arr_to_get_str(arr);
alert(url);

//http://localhost/test.php?q=products_id > 20 AND products_name like %hello world%
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vSuDZ/

Comment: @mingfish_004 Check the above answer I have made changes in it.